# enitre function that preserve the rationals?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's a question i would be curious to know the answer

The question is: what is the set of all entire functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\mathbb{Q})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'd imagine all polynomials with rational coefficients qualify?

Comment: @orion No, even considering all polynomials with rational coefficients only, they can have $f(\mathbb{Q})\subsetneq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: We evidently(?) have $f(z) = az+b$ with $a\in \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}$. I strongly suspect these are all, but proving it isn't obvious.

Comment: Oh right, we have to avoid any functions with irrational inverses... In that case, I belive @DanielFischer is right. I suppose that if we ignore "entire function" requirement, we get all the rational Mobius transformations?

Comment: There's a lot of them, see [Functions that take rationals to rationals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167620/functions-that-take-rationals-to-rationals). The question is about $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, but the intermediate function $g$ I construct in my answer is analytic $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ and maps rationals to rationals, but is _not_ a polynomial. It should be reasonably clear that there's continuum many similar functions.

Comment: @orion,Daniel Fisher: sorry i was thinking of $\subseteq$ and i wrote =. I've edited.

Comment: In that case, all rational polynomials and quotients of rational polynomials are alright.

Comment: @orion: Quotients of polynomials are not entire.

Comment: Sure, I just expanded on my previous answer (Mobius transformations) but of course among entire functions, only polynomials apply.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat surprisingly, even much more can be achieved:

MR0301195 
Barth, K. F.; Schneider, W. J.
Entire functions mapping arbitrary countable dense sets and their complements onto each other. 
J. London Math. Soc. (2) 4 (1971/72), 482–488.

It is proved that if A, B are two countable dense sets in the complex plane, then there exists an entire function w=f(z) such that f(z)∈B if and only if z∈A. This rather surprising result answers a question first raised by P. Erdős.

This applies to "complex rational" numbers, but in another paper they treat the real case:

Barth, K. F.; Schneider, W. J.
Entire functions mapping countable dense subsets of the reals onto each other monotonically. 
J. London Math. Soc. (2) 2 1970 620–626.