# Is this relating to continuous functions conjecture correct?

Tags: real-analysis

**Preliminary.** (my actual question is below)

Here is a **false** conjecture I came up with.

> **Conjecture**. For any arbitrary rational-number valued function $\tilde f: \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$, there exists a real-number valued
>   function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, such that for all $q\in \mathbb
>  Q$:
>
> 1. $f(q)=\tilde f(q)$, and
> 2. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

**Obviously, this is incorrect,** as I found out immediately after thinking of it, since a rational valued function can still have infinitely oscillating sequences defined on it.

My intuition for why it was correct was: there are an uncountable number of irrational numbers between any two rational numbers $a,b$, but only a countably infinite number of rational numbers. Therefore it might be possible to come up with a sequence of irrational numbers that "fills in the gaps, in such a way as to make $f$ continuous". Obviously my intuition was wrong.

---

**My actual question:**

**So therefore I came up with the complete opposite conjecture:**

> **Conjecture.** For any arbitrary continuous real valued function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, define $\tilde f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ to be the rational-valued function such that $\forall q\in \mathbb Q: \tilde f(q):= f(q)$.
>
> Then $f$ is the only continuous real valued function such that $\forall q\in \mathbb Q: f(q)=\tilde f(q)$.

**Is this conjecture correct?**

Comment: This definition doesn’t make sense; if you restrict a function from reals to reals to rational inputs it will generally still produce irrational outputs. Once you fix that, yes, the statement is true, it follows from the fact that the rationals are dense in the reals.

Comment: Worth noting:  it's not easy to come up with interesting continuous functions that take rationals to rationals.  Rational functions have this property (quotients of polynomials with rational coefficients) but what else?  They exist but it is hard to write them down...see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167620/functions-that-take-rationals-to-rationals)