# Analytic functions mapping rationals to rationals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, analytic-functions

$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$One can show that there are uncountably many continuous function $f:\RR\to\RR$ with the property that $f(q)\in\QQ$ for $q\in\QQ$. It's also not hard to show that there are still uncountable many such functions which are $C^\infty$. My questions is:

> Are there uncountably many *analytic* functions $f:\RR\to\RR$ for which $f(q)\in\QQ$ for every $q\in\QQ$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [this beautiful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169450/173410) by Makholm and note that there are uncountably many enumerations of the rationals (there are plenty of parameters open to being varied here, but I guess this is the first that catches the eye in the answer).

Comment: Also, note [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42460/is-a-real-power-series-that-maps-rationals-to-rationals-defined-by-a-rational-fun) in the comments of the linked question, which also answers the question, but in more general terms. Makholm's answer bakes even more properties into the analytic function (behavior at infinity).