# Derivatives of real functions which preserve the rationals

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I am looking at functions from $\mathbb{R}$ or an open set of it to $\mathbb{R}$ which send rational numbers to rational numbers i.e. $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.  I will call such functions $\mathbb{Q}$-functions.

I am looking at derivatives and asking whether a $\mathbb{Q}$-function which is differentiable (in the usual real sense) can have a derivative which is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-function.

To illustrate the question, consider the similar one for anti-derivatives.  In this case, the answer is that a $\mathbb{Q}$-function might have an anti-derivative which is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-function.  An example is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $(0, \infty)$.  The anti-derivative is $\log(x) + C$ and no choice of $C$ makes this a $\mathbb{Q}$-function.

Back to derivatives, I have failed to find such an example.  I did some research and I found a Math Overflow answer which said that a continuous $\mathbb{Q}$-function is either piecewise rational or highly irregular.  Unfortunately, I cannot find it again to check whether I understood it correctly.  If it is correct then the answer to my question is that the derivative of a differentiable $\mathbb{Q}$-function will also be a $\mathbb{Q}$-function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a differentiable function such that $f(\mathbb Q) \subseteq \mathbb Q$ but $f'(\mathbb Q) \not \subseteq \mathbb Q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788377/is-there-a-differentiable-function-such-that-f-mathbb-q-subseteq-mathbb-q) (found using [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(%5Cmathbb%7BQ%7D)%20%5Csubseteq%20%5Cmathbb%7BQ%7D%24&p=1))

Comment: I think you can, just choose two functions that have the same derivative in 0 that is for example $\sqrt{2}$ such that one is greater than the other, then choose affine by parts function between both

Comment: @BrunoB Yes it does.  My searching skills are not good enough,

Comment: @badjohn: The site's built-in search function is not overly effective, in my experience. I generally search it via Google.